# Why doesn't the sulfate anion in copper(II) sulfate have a subscript of 2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, structural-formula

So I'm being asked to find the chemical formula for copper(II) sulfate.

I thought it would be written as:

$$\ce{Cu(SO4)2}$$

Apparently it's written as:

$$\ce{Cu(SO4)}$$

Can anyone please explain to me why the latter answer is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The sulfate anion, $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ has a charge of -2. Copper can have cations with either +1 or +2. So the two possible copper sulfates are cuprous sulfate (copper(I) sulfate), $\ce{Cu2SO4}$, and cupric sulfate (copper(II) sulfate), $\ce{CuSO4}$.